# What's difference of solr full import & full import with clean?

Tags: solr, lucene, dataimporthandler

There's two ways to full import in solr,one is with clean another is without, what's difference between them two ? Thanks.

Jeff Zhang

Comment: If you add param Clean your full-import starts with clean slate, meaning: the DIH will delete all existing documents before doing full-import.

Comment: There were some problems with the Clean param before and I'm not sure if they have been fixed. Do you have some kind of problem or you're just curious :)

Comment: I have some issues with Clean in SOLR 5.0.0 and it looks like it doesn't clean old data. Anyone had same issue ?